# XSLT 2.0 Count of number of iterations after filter and grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to find number of iteration done by the below XSL for loop

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[SOME_FIELD != 'da']" group-by="concat(SOME_FIELD1,'+',SOME_FIELD2)">
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

I need the count out of this for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you just need distinct-values:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(
    current-group()[SOME_FIELD != 'da']/concat(SOME_FIELD1,'+',SOME_FIELD2)))"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`for-each-group` is not a loop and an empty `for-each-group` is probably not even evaluated at all. If you create groups and want to count the number of groups then group into a variable with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="groups" as="element(group)*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[SOME_FIELD != 'da']" group-by="concat(SOME_FIELD1,'+',SOME_FIELD2)">
    <group>...</group>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
```

then you can use `count($groups)` to get the number of groups.